# Issues with dimensions of arrays ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, numpy

I have this np.array called data:

```
data=np.array([ 2.7,  2.9,  1. ,  4. ,  4.3,  1.3,  2.9,  2.2,  4.2,  8. , .... , 1.5,  1. ,  2.1,  0.3, 0.3,  2.5,  1.7])
Size: (366,) Type: Array of float64
```

and i have a matrix called harmonics:

```
p=365.25
x=np.arange(1,367,1)
harmonics=np.matrix([np.cos(2*np.pi/p*x), np.sin(2*np.pi/p*x),
          np.cos(4*np.pi/p*x), np.sin(4*np.pi/p*x), np.ones(len(x))])

Size: (5,366) Type: Array of float64
```

I want to do a multiple linear regression so i did this code:
First i transpose the data array with:

```
data=np.transpose(data)
```

After i tried to do a multiple regression with this code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
bb=clf.fit(harmonics,data)
```

But i get this error: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 366]`

I'm not understanding very well the error but i think maybe it's about the dimensions of the matrix.

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check whether the `transpose` did anything?  `data` is 1d!

Comment: transpose did not anything

Comment: right `transpose` just reverses the dimensions.  It does not add a dimension.  What does `fit` expect about the dimensions of its arguments?